# Passing Arrays in array JSON from Android to rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, object

This should be the JSON output:

```
{
"ph_immunizations_attributes": [
       {"immunization_id": 1},
       {"immunization_id": 2}
]
}
```

How will i translate it in my Android codes to post in my rails server

And here's the code:

```
List<NameValuePair> immunizatioValuePairs = new ArrayList();
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jA = new JSONArray();
jObj.put("immmunization_id", 1);

jA.put(jObj);
main.put("ph_immunizations_attributes", jA);


immunizatioValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ph_immunizations_attributes",             main.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(immunizatioValuePairs));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jA = new JSONArray();
jObj.put("immunization_id", 1);  // 1 --> get the values here either from other class or array or whatever.

jA.put(jObj);
main.put("ph_immunizations_attributes", jA);
```

Try this and let me know

Comment: But how can I remove the backslashes when I convert and pass the JSON to the server?

Comment: where is the backslash here?

Comment: When we check the server logs, here's the the result with back slash:

{"ph_immunizations_attributes"=>"{\"ph_immunizations_attributes\":[{\"immmunization_id\":1}]}"}

Comment: how do you deal with association in rails app? having problems with the user_id insertion @Aniruddha